# How to solve ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack?

Tags: python, count

i use python 2.7 and i try to find how each of the POS in my file occur i write this code :

```
     from collections import Counter
     f = open("POS.txt","r")
     text = f.read()
     print(text)
     counts = Counter(tag for word,tag in text)
     print(counts)
```

and the output was as here :

```
      File "C:/Python27/Lib/countPOS.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
      counts = Counter(tag for word,tag in text)
      ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How to solve this error ? and this is the input in my file:

```
 [(u'\u0627', 'JJ'), (u'\u0644', 'NNP'), (u'\u062d', 'NNP'), (u'\u064e', 
 'NNP'), (u'\u0631', 'NNP'), (u'\u0652', 'NNP'), (u'\u0628', 'NNP'), 
 (u'\u064f', 'NN')]
```

Comment: wait: your file contains this exact contents as ASCII? then you cannot just read it and expect that the tuples rebuild themselves.

Comment: here `text` is a string. You're trying to unpack a string into 2 items. Since the string is longer than 2 elements, you get this message

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `for x,y in seq` expects each element in seq to have two parts, i.e. a list of two-element tuples.  But since it's text, each element is a single character and cannot be further unpacked, hence the "need more than 1 value to unpack" error.

Comment: yes, exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: You said "Since the string is longer than 2 elements,you get this message", but that error would occur even with a string of length 2.  The problem is that the elements in `text` cannot be further unpacked.

Comment: exactly what I'm saying, except from that delirious part, it is! you're right

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre , thank you any way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this problem because variable 'text' type is string after you read data from the file. You need to convert data type.

Here is the working code:

```
from collections import Counter
import ast

f = open("POS.txt", "r")
text = f.read()
# print(type(text)) returns string


text = ast.literal_eval(text)
# print (type(text)) returns list

counts = Counter(tag for word, tag in text)
print(counts)
```